# Ignore failed factorisations in numpy/scipy cholesky factorisations

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

I'm trying to compute the Cholesky decomposition of a large number of hermitian matrices,

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg
H = np.random.rand(1000000,10,10)
H = 0.5*(H + H.transpose(0,2,1)) + 1.01*np.eye(10)
```

The decompositions can be computed very cleanly:

```py
L = linalg.cholesky(H)
# executes in 553 ms
```

In practice, one or two of these matrices will end up being only positive *semidefinite*, causing the function to throw a `LinAlgError` and give up. For my purposes, it's only important that most of them work, and the rest can be removed from the sample.

My question is, **Is there a faster / vectorised way to get the following behaviour?**

```py
L = np.zeros_like(H)
falied_indices=[]
for n in range(H.shape[0]):
    try:
        L[n] = linalg.cholesky(H[n])
    except linalg.LinAlgError:
        failed_indices.append(n)

# executes in 5.3 s
```

Comment: An alternative would be to generate only positive definite matrices, for example by P = H*H.transpose + eps*np.eye

Comment: In the actual code, the matrices come from elsewhere - the code here is just an example for testing.